# How to run a Excel spreadsheet on another computer with VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript, automation

I have the following situation:

There is a Excel workbook saved on another computer on my network. I need to execute the file on that computer, because it is connected with a Big Screen to show some data. I was trying to automate the execution of the workbook but all that I can get is to make it run on MY computer, and I need it to run on THAT computer

The relevant part of the vbs code that I am using is the following:

```
Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objXL.Visible = True
Set objXLWorkbook = objXL.Workbooks.Open(path)
```

I know that this method can only open Workbooks on my computer. Anyone knows how to make it run Excel on another computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot - out of the box - run programs or scripts on remote computers. Otherwise, it would be even less difficult than it is today to install a virus remotely. Your vbs could simply install and activate a virus instead of an excel file.

Nonetheless its quite a common thing that one wants to do every now and again (the remote task, not the virus - especially administrators love to scare users by remotely opening some funny stuff).

Have a look at an [article from Bill Stewart](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/windows-powershell/powershell-run-programs-remotely-141270)  where he explains how to use Powershell to accomplish your task.
The required setup on the remote computer still needs to be done once.

Comment: I think that the article solves my problem, I'll try it out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you. Compare [How do I ask questions here? in the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)